# Reading from CSV with value numbers formatted

Tags: c#, csv, split, streamreader

The process that I wish to achieve it that I read from a CSV file and automatically the system creates a new CSV file in different format.

I am able to read and format the CSV file however I have issues when dealing with number formatting as the values are formatted in thousands(1,000). For example when I read from the CSV and split each line with ',' my values change.

Ex Line 1: Test Name, Test Desc, Test Currency, 12,500

var line1 = line.split(',');

This splits the value 12 & 500 because of the , delimiter. How can I get the number as a whole amount please?

```
  using (var reader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    var values = line.Split(',');
                }
            }
```

Comment: u could try some regex where it check the , is not between 2 numbers. But that might also not work depending on what data is in it.

Answer (score 3):

You cant. When a CSV file contains numbers (or any text with a , in it) it needs to quote the fields. It is impossible for simple code (i.e. not AI) to differentiate in the way your human eye can.

> Ex Line 1: Test Name, Test Desc, Test Currency, 12,500

Should be:

> Ex Line 1: "Test Name", "Test Desc", "Test Currency", "12,500"

Common CSV parsers/libraries will know how to handle this (e.g. [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/))

If you have control over the CSV file generation, then you should make this change. If it's from a 3rd party then see if you can get them to make a change.

There may be an edge case in your example if there is always a space after fields and not in the number fields. Your delimiter then becomes ", " instead of just ','

Answer (score 0):

**Side note:**

You should consider not to use culture-specific separators in a .csv file because it *always* leads to headaches when the data is exported/imported with different regional settings.

**Possible solutions:**

- I suggest to dump and parse numbers (dates, etc.) with invariant culture:

  `myNumber.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`
- If you really need to dump numbers with comma decimal sign enclose the field into quotes. This does not turn the numbers strings as .csv has no type information.

**Excel vs. the .csv format**

*Another side note for Excel*: Microsoft's .csv handling is somewhat confusing and contradicts the [RFC Standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180). When you export a .csv in Excel the numbers are always dumped using the regional settings. To avoid the confusion with delimiters, Excel uses a different character (usually semicolon) as delimiter if the decimal separator is comma.

The used delimiter is the one is set as the list separator in the operating system's regional settings and in .NET can be retrieved via the `CultureInfo.TextInfo.ListSeparator` property.

I find this solution from Microsoft quite unfortunate as .csv files dumped by different regional settings cannot be always read on another computer and this only causes troubles since decades.